# Installing OpenMx package in R on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: r, gcc, g++, ubuntu-18.04, openmx

I get the following error when trying to install (`install.packages("OpenMx")`) OpenMx in R on Ubuntu 18.04. I am not familiar with compiling C code, so I ask that you "dumb it down" for me a bit.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/OpenMx_2.12.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3338967 bytes (3.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘OpenMx’ ...
** package ‘OpenMx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
NOTE: ./configure is not an autoconf generated script.
Change default C/C++ compiler and default compile flags by editing ~/.R/Makevars
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include" -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/StanHeaders/include" -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/BH/include" -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rpf/include"   -fopenmp     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c Compute.cpp -o Compute.o
In file included from omxState.h:31:0,
                 from glue.h:23,
                 from Compute.cpp:24:
omxDefines.h:247:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Core>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:171: recipe for target 'Compute.o' failed
make: *** [Compute.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘OpenMx’
* removing ‘/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/OpenMx’
* restoring previous ‘/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/OpenMx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenMx’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpbljrRR/downloaded_packages’
```

---

**Update 1**

It looks like the error may actual be a result of the `RcppEigen` package not being installed. When I try to install the package I get 10,000 lines of error messages. Here's the first:

```
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/adam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Core:392:0,
                 from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:60:39: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
 template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128>  { enum { value = true }; };
```

---

**Update 2**

I got `RcppEigen` successfully installed, but `OpenMx` still will not compile. The *only* error is at the end of a very long (thousands of lines) stream of compilation warnings. The error: `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'OpenMx'`

Comment: fatal error is on Eigen/Core, try install `sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev` please, also updating gcc could help

Comment: Installed `libeigen3-dev` but still getting the same error

Comment: @Brigadeiro how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong here, and you are not helping by showing only partial output.

For starters, the [package clearly depends on other binary packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenMx/index.html) but you did not tell us if those are installed, or not.  *If you had earlier errors you did not show* then you, simply put, have no chance of installing OpenMX.

So I would do the following: ensure that *all* packages from the link above and under `Imports:` and `LinkingTo:` are installed.  Test that by loading them one by one R via, eg, `library(Rcpp)`.

If and when *all* requirements are met, then attempt installing OpenMX, and update your questions will relevant error messages, if any.   But in short the comment above about the `libeigen3-dev` package is completely misleading as `RcppEigen` does not use that package.

Lastly, the `r-sig-debian` list is friendly and patient and a place for Debian/Ubuntu questions.

*Edit:* Based on OP's edit, one shortcut maybe to `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen`.

Comment: That was the full error message I got when trying to install OpenMx. Based on your suggestion, it looks like the error is resulting from the unmet dependency of the `RcppEigen` package. I updated the question to include the beginning of that error message.

Comment: There are no errors until the end, which basically says that RcppEigen did not compile. I believe it's a problem with R 3.5, because it works just fine on 3.4. FWIW, I tried installing through apt and it didn't work (says it depends on r-api-3.4).

Comment: It's really pretty straightforward.  You can compile it all from source / from within R to install into `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. So if RcppEigen fails it almost always is due to the fact that one its depends needs a rebuild. Or, and the *best* thing you have going for you is the README at CRAN and the Rutter 3.4/3.5.  It is easy to just use 3.5 throughout: all my Ubuntu machines do.  I think you simply have not pointed at the Rutter 3,5 repo -- see the th short para here: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html.  It *will* give your R 3.5.2 *and* RcppEigen.

Comment: All of the packages dependencies for `RcppEigen` are installed. I appreciate that this is straightforward for you, but it is not for me - I am not a C/C++ programmer and am not familiar with compiling its code.

Comment: You have to understand that I cannot help you if you do not show the *error* message.  You still just display an irrelevant warning.  And nobody claimed that OpenMX was simple, small or easy.  Maybe suggest to them to provide you with a Docker container....

Comment: I got `RcppEigen` installed successfully, but still no luck with `OpenMx`. See Update 2 above for more info. Only 1 error message in the entire output, which included thousands of line of code.

Comment: That is just restating that there was an error, and does not help.  There will be a message somewhere.  But I only stand behind Rcpp and RcppEigen and am not an OpenMX user so you may have to rely on their team.  Sorry.